# tablesorter filter is not hiding while hiding column in table

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

i am able to remove the column data and header on checkbox action above. But as i am using tablesorter plugin . the  filters are not hiding and going away. it is consuming extra space which we want to provide for the extend table view.

please take a look at two images to get a better reference and understanding?

[image]

[image]

i am hoping @Mottie will come up with some solution .

here is my present structure

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="someussta">
          <div class="btn-cal-group pull-right">    <a href="#" id="downsta" class="btn btn-sm bg-blue">Export Results Excel</a>
          <a href="#" id="testussta" type="button" onclick="exportPDFResults();" class="btn btn-sm bg-blue">Export Results pdf</a></div>


                                        <thead>
                               <tr>   <div> <b> ** Customize Column ** </b> </div> <div id="grpChkussta">
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Dcou" /> State
    <input type="checkbox" name="sresu" /> Search Result
<input type="checkbox" name="mflag" /> Flag
<input type="checkbox" name="mcomm" /> Comment
<input type="checkbox" name="mname" /> Trademark Name
<input type="checkbox" name="mtype" />Trademark No.
  <input type="checkbox" name="mleg" /> Legal Status</p>

            </div></tr>
                          <tr>  <div id="sticky" class="sticky">
                                 <th style="width: 10px"><input type="checkbox"  id="inp-chkboxsta"></th>
                                 <!--   <th>Mark Image</th> -->
                                   <th class="Dcou">State</th>
                                 <th class="sresu">Search Result</th>
                                <th class="mflag"> Flag </th>
                                <th class="mcomm"> Comment </th>
                                <th class="mname">Trademark Name</th>
                                <th class="mtype">Trademark No.</th>
                                <th class="mleg">Legal Status</th>
                                      <!-- <th>Web link</th> -->
                        </div>         </tr>     </thead>     

                      <tbody>
                              {% for result in cat.results %}
                              <tr id="someussta" class="content">
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" data-pid="{{result.id_}}" class="inpchksta"></td>
                                <td class="Dcou">{% for state in result.designatedContractedStates %}
                                                                        {{state}}
                                                                        {% endfor %}</td>

                                <td class="sresu">{{result.trademarkType}}</td>

                             <td width="125" class="{{result.id_}}">



                  <td class="mname"><a data-toggle="modal" class="tm" data-target="#TMResultModal" data-tid="{{result.id_}}">{{result.markName}}</a></td>
                   <td class="mreg">{{ (result.registrtionNo|string).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') }}</td>
                    <td class="mleg">{{result.legalStatus}}</td>
                                <!-- <td>{{result.goodsServices}}</td> -->
                              </tr>

                                                                    {% endfor %}</tbody>
                                                            </table>
```

Here is the function that i am using to hide my column from table.

```
$(function () {
        var $chk = $("#grpChkussta input:checkbox");
        var $tbl = $("#someussta");
        $chk.prop('checked', true);
        $chk.click(function () {
            var colToHide = $tbl.find("." + $(this).attr("name"));
            $(colToHide).toggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Mottie i hope you understand the problem i am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter row is built dynamically, so the cells do not include the name of each column. This can be added using the [`filter_cellFilter` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-cellfilter)

```
$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
      filter_cellFilter : ["Dcou", "sresu", "mflag", "mcomm", "mname", "mtype", "mleg"]
    }
  });
});
```

Note:

- The HTML is not valid. Wrapping a `<div>` around table cells may not work predictably in all browsers.
- The HTML provided doesn't appear to be for the same table in the screenshots, so if you have multiple tables with togglable columns, it might be easier to use the [column selector widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html). It also wouldn't be necessary to name every table cell because the widget using `nth-child()` css selectors to hide the columns.
- There is also a [sticky header widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html).